# touchesMoved doesn't record all points in a UIView (Swift implementation)

Tags: swift2

I am new to coding in general. Recently starting coding in Swift.
Working on a simple Swift based drawing app in which I need to record an array of points over which user touches screen and moves finger.

I am using touchesMoved to record touch locations in a UIView. touchesMoved doesn't record all the points if user moves finger fast enough. If finger movement is slow, it records all points. I looked at earlier questions regarding this on this forum but couldn't figure out how to implement those. Any suggestions or direction on where to look for the answer will be highly appreciated.

Attached is the code I am using

```
import UIKit
class SketchView: UIView {

var lines = [Line]()
var lastPoint: CGPoint!            //this is to track last touch of the user


override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    let touch = touches.first! as UITouch
    lastPoint = touch.locationInView(self)

}


override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    let touch = touches.first! as UITouch
    let newPoint = touch.locationInView(self)

    lines.append(Line(start: lastPoint, end: newPoint))
    lastPoint = newPoint

    self.setNeedsDisplay()

}

override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    print(" Sketch points number is \(lines.count)")

}


override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    CGContextBeginPath(context)

    for line in lines {
        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, line.start.x, line.start.y)
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, line.end.x, line.end.y)

    }

    //CGContextSetLineCap(context, .Round)
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 0, 0, 0, 1)
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 5)
    CGContextStrokePath(context)

}



}
```

Just to confirm that points are missing in my array, in the image below I am showing the x-coordinates stored in the array for a line a drew on screen.

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: If it wasn't clear in the post above, question is how can I store all the points that user touches while moving his finger on the screen. Thanks

Comment: Hi Neeraj can you share the project over github or something similar so that we can have a look and debug.

Comment: Hi Jeetendra, Thanks for offering to help. You can download the code from here https://github.com/Neeraj3pathi/SimpleDrawing/issues/1

Comment: Neeraj That works fine in my system. Looks like it is not a code problem but some other.

Comment: Jeetendra, thanks for checking. When you say it works fine. I am guessing you mean that you see a continuous line when you draw? If yes, the problem isn't the continuous line, but the points that get saved in the "lines" array. "lines" array that records the touch points in the touchesMoved function doesn't save all the points over which finger touch is scanned. We see a continuos line because CG adds all the likes between the discontinous points in "lines" array. I need to record all the touch points in lines array so that I can play with them later.